# JComboBox and JTextField disappearing when button is pressed

Tags: java, swing

I'm having some trouble with a simple application I'm creating to count the number of clicks per second. The code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class CPSFrame implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel borderPanel, settings;
    JButton click;
    String[] timesList = {"5","10","15","20","25","30"};
    JComboBox times;
    JTextField showCps;


    public CPSFrame() {

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CPSFrame c = new CPSFrame();
                c.drawGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void drawGui() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        borderPanel = new JPanel();
        settings = new JPanel();
        click = new JButton("Click me!");
        times = new JComboBox(timesList);
        showCps = new JTextField();

        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("CPS Calculator");
        {
            borderPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            frame.add(borderPanel);
            {
                borderPanel.add(click);

                settings.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
                borderPanel.add(settings, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                {
                    settings.add(times);

                    settings.add(showCps);

                }
            }
        }

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }
}
```

For some reason, if I resize the JFrame and press `click`, both `times` and `showCPS` disappear. I have a feeling it has something to do with the way I have the BorderLayout set up, but I'm not sure.

Here is a [video](https://www.screenr.com/xvPN) of what is happening.

edit: updated the code and added a video of what is happening.

Comment: Seems to work okay for me.  Perhaps make sure you're creating and showing the UI from within the context of the EDT. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: It works for me as well. I would recommend that you create your GUI in the CPSFrame non-static code and not build it within the static main method. Instead in the main method, simply create your CPSFrame object, wind it up and let it run.

Comment: First, I do not understand your use of extraneous blocks of code (e.g., code between braces) - for example, "settings.add(times);" and "settings.add(showCPS);" do not need to be separated from the other code. Second, I do not see where you are adding an action listener to the "click" button.

Comment: I haven't added an action listener for the button yet. The extraneous blocks were how I learned it in my computer science class, and it doesn't effect how the code compiles. Neither of the things you pointed out effect the rendering of `times` and `showCPS`.

Answer (score -1):

Works fine for me (Java 1.6, Win) and nothing disappears after resize and click. Try to specify the location of c.click explicitly c.borderPanel.add(c.click,BorderLayout.CENTER);
Maybe there are Java implementations (platforms, versions) where BorderLayout don't like unspecified location.

Comment: As per the BorderLayout API, adding to BorderLayout in a default fashion (without a second parameter constant) automatically places the component BorderLayout.CENTER. This is not version, L&F or platform dependent.

Comment: hmm, still having the same issue after adding BorderLayout.CENTER and moving the frame code out of the main method. I've updated the original post with more information.